# USB Host Mode solution for Motorola-Droid phones

Tags: arduino, usb, communication, host, motorola-droid

I would like to control an Arduino device with a Motorola phone.

I have a Lilypad (preferred), an Uno, and a Mega Arduino board and I have two Motorola phones (a Droid Bionic and a Droid Razr Maxx) both running Android 4.1.2.  According to an App called "USB Host Diagnostics" neither phone has USB Host Mode capability.

A variety of sites suggest the problem is that the phone doesn't provide enough power to the Arduino.  Their solution requires cutting up and reconnecting the wires inside the cables.  Others say the creation of a special "dongle" solves the problem, as long as it is in the phone when it starts to boot up but is removed before it finishes. Others suggest that it requires rooting the phone, which I'm afraid is probably beyond my comfort level and skill set. And many of these postings are several years old.

Has anyone figured out an smarter/better way to either enable or work-around the host mode capability issue of these phones? Or would it just be easier to find a used Nexus or Galaxy phone?